Finding the lower bound of the Lp norm of finite Fourier sum on [0,1] using Hua’s Lemma
So here’s the question:
Let $f(\alpha) = \sum_{1\leq x \leq X}e(\alpha x^k)$ for $k \geq 2$ and some large $X$.
Given Hua’s Lemma, we know that for $1 \leq j \leq k$,
$ \int_0^1   |f(\alpha)|^{2j} d\alpha \ll X^{2^j-j+\epsilon}$.
Show that for any positive s, $ \int_0^1   |f(\alpha)|^{s} d\alpha \gg X^{s/2 - \epsilon} $.
The first thought I have is to either use the interpolation rule or use some trivial bound. For interpolation we can set
$ ||f||_{La} \leq ||f||_{Ls}^{\lambda} ||f||_{Lb}^{1-\lambda}$,
and then just wish for some a,b to make it work. So hopefully a and b are some power of 2, if we want to apply Hua’s lemma. But I don’t see how I can continue.
On the other hand, I’m not sure if there’s any trivial lower bound for f.
How should I continue? I really appreciate any hint!!!

Edit - Here is a full solution that covers all options for $s>0$. We start by noting that for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$\widehat{f}\left(n\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(\alpha\right)e\left(-n\alpha\right)d\alpha=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{1\le x\le X}e\left(\alpha x^{k}\right)\cdot e\left(-n\alpha\right)d\alpha
=$$$$\sum_{1\le x\le X}\int_{0}^{1}e\left(\alpha\left(x^{k}-n\right)\right)d\alpha=\sum_{1\le x\le X}\mathbb{1}_{\left\{ 0\right\} }\left(x^{k}-n\right)=\mathbb{1}_{\left[X\right]}\left(n^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)$$ Then by Parseval's identity $\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{2}d\alpha=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\vert\widehat{f}\left(n\right)\vert^{2}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{1}_{\left[X\right]}\left(n^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)=X$, which also covers the case $s=2$. For $s>2$, let $p:=\frac{s}{2}\in\left(1,\infty\right)$. Then by the reverse Hölder's inequality (letting the other function in the inequality's formulation to be the constant function 1) $\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{s}d\alpha=\vert\vert f^{s}\vert\vert_{1}\ge\vert\vert f^{s}\vert\vert_{\frac{1}{p}}=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{s\cdot\frac{2}{s}}d\alpha\right)^{\frac{s}{2}}=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{2}d\alpha\right)^{\frac{s}{2}}=X^{\frac{s}{2}}$. For $0<s<2$, use interpolation inequality with $s,b=4$ and $a=2$ (using your notations). Then we have $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1-\lambda}{s}+\frac{\lambda}{4}\Longrightarrow\lambda=\frac{4-2s}{4-s}\in\left(0,1\right)$ and $$\left(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{2}d\alpha\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le\left(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{s}d\alpha\right)^{\frac{1-\lambda}{s}}\cdot\left(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{4}d\alpha\right)^{\frac{\lambda}{4}}$$ and by Hua's lemma (with $j=2$) $$X^{\frac{1}{2}}\ll\left(\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{s}d\alpha\right)^{\frac{1-\lambda}{s}}X^{\frac{\lambda}{4}\left(2+\delta\right)}$$ for all $\delta>0$. Plug in $\lambda=\frac{4-2s}{4-s}$, we get $$\int_{0}^{1}\vert f\left(\alpha\right)\vert^{s}d\alpha\gg\left(X^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\lambda}{4}\left(2+\delta\right)}\right)^{\frac{s}{1-\lambda}}=\left(X^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\frac{4-2s}{4-s}}{4}\left(2+\delta\right)}\right)^{\frac{s}{1-\frac{4-2s}{4-s}}}
=X^{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\frac{4-2s}{4-s}}{4}\left(2+\delta\right)\right)\left(4-s\right)}$$$$=X^{\frac{1}{2}\left(s+\delta s-2\delta\right)} = X^{\frac{s}{2}-\varepsilon}$$ for all $\varepsilon:=\frac{2\delta-\delta s}{2} > 0$. This finishes the proof of the remaining case.

Thanks Omer! I think I forgot to use the reverse Hölder for this one. And I think for s between 0 and 2 we do need to use something else. The question is from Dr. Trevor Wooley’s webpage, HW set.1. https://www.math.purdue.edu/~twooley/2023ant/2023ant.html. It’s mention that we need to use Hua’s Lemma on this one, but all we get for Hua’s lemma are upper bounds, no lower bounds. So I was thinking maybe some interpolation tricks, or use your way, reverse Hölder. But I cannot see how to apply interpolation if Hua’s lemma is given. Thanks again for your answer for s>2 tho!

@TommySoon See the rest of the proof, also covering the case $0<s\leq2$

Thank you so much Omer, it is so well explained!
